# Total negative and quantity display

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

hello to all you can call me Neff, I'm new on the site, and of course beginner on React,
I explain my problem to you

I want to create a website e commerce, for my first test I created my products (see picture)

Today I use *my sql* to display the products

so my problem is

I can not map, in the photos it will be easier to understand

on one side I can display my comic without the quantity and the other the quantity without comic, you see my problem

I'm sorry for my english,
and thanks in advance for your help everyone
Neff

```
const initState = {
category: [{id: 1, name:'bieres'}],
items: [


    {id:1,title: "Hype PA (Demi-Pinte)", desc:"Pression - Biére Blonde", qty:"25 cl", img: hypePa, price: 3.50, ctg: 1, },
    {id:2,title:'Hype PA (Pinte)', desc: "Pression - Biére Blonde ",qty:"50 cl", price:6 ,img: hypePa, bieres: "bieres",},
    {id:3,title:'Houblons des blés (Demi-Pinte)', desc: "Pression - Biére Blonde",qty:"25 cl", price: 3.50, img: houblonCommeLesBles, ctg: "bieres",},
    {id:4,title:'Houblons des blés (Pinte)', desc: "Pression - Blonde ",qty:"50 cl",  price:6 ,img: houblonCommeLesBles, ctg: "bieres",},
    {id:5,title:'Session IPA (3,6°)', desc: "Biére Blonde ",qty:"Bouteille",  price:5,img:sessionIpa, ctg: "bieres", },
    {id:6,title:'Sour Kefir (5,9°)', desc: "Biére Blonde", qty:"Bouteille", price:6,img: sourkefir, ctg: "bieres",},
    {id:7,title:'Brown Ale (5,4°)', desc: "Biére blonde", qty:"Bouteille", price:5.5,img: brownAle, ctg: "bieres",},

],

addedItems:[],
total: 0,

 }
  const cartReducer= (state = initState,action)=>{



//INSIDE HOME COMPONENT
if(action.type === ADD_TO_CART){
      let addedItem = state.items.find(item=> item.id === action.id)
      //check if the action id exists in the addedItems
     let existed_item= state.addedItems.find(item=> action.id === item.id)
     if(existed_item)
     {
        addedItem.quantity += 1 
         return{
            ...state,
             total: state.total + addedItem.price 
              }
    }
     else{
        addedItem.quantity = 1;
        //calculating the total
        let newTotal = state.total + addedItem.price 

        return{
            ...state,
            addedItems: [...state.addedItems, addedItem],
            total : newTotal
        }

    };
}
if(action.type === REMOVE_ITEM){
    let itemToRemove= state.addedItems.find(item=> action.id === item.id)
    let new_items = state.addedItems.filter(item=> action.id !== item.id)

    //calculating the total
    let newTotal = state.total - (itemToRemove.price * itemToRemove.quantity )
    console.log(itemToRemove)
    return{
        ...state,
        addedItems: new_items,
        total: newTotal
    }
}



//INSIDE CART COMPONENT
if(action.type=== ADD_QUANTITY){
    let addedItem = state.items.find(item=> item.id === action.id)
      addedItem.quantity += 1 
      let newTotal = state.total + addedItem.price
      return{
          ...state,
          total: newTotal
      }
}
if(action.type=== SUB_QUANTITY){  
    let addedItem = state.items.find(item=> item.id === action.id) 
    //if the qt == 0 then it should be removed
    if(addedItem.quantity === 1){
        let new_items = state.addedItems.filter(item=>item.id !== action.id)
        let newTotal = state.total - addedItem.price
        return{
            ...state,
            addedItems: new_items,
            total: newTotal
        }
    }
    else {
        addedItem.quantity -= 1
        let newTotal = state.total - addedItem.price
        return{
            ...state,
            total: newTotal
        }
    }

}

if(action.type=== ADD_SHIPPING){
      return{
          ...state,
          total: state.total + 6
      }
}

if(action.type=== 'SUB_SHIPPING'){
    return{
        ...state,
        total: state.total - 6
     }
      }

  else{
  return state
    }

 }

export default cartReducer;
```

1

```
getRandom = async () => {

    const res = await axios.get(
        'http://localhost:5252/api/allproducts'
    )
    this.setState({ data: res.data })
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.getRandom()
}



render() {
    console.log(this.state.data)
    console.log(this.state.data)
    const externalCloseBtn = <button className="crossModal" style= 
  {{ position: 'absolute', top: '15px', right: '15px' }} onClick= 
{this.toggle}>&times;</button>;

    let datas = this.state.data.map(datass => {
        return (
            <div className="homeProduct">
                <button className="buttonContainerHome" onClick={() 
      => this.toggle(datass.id)}>{this.props.buttonLabel}

                    <Media  >
                        <Media body 
 className="mediaBodyContainerHome">
                            <div className="mediaBodyTitle">
                                <Media heading 
     className='MediaTextHome'>
                                    {datass.title}
                                </Media>

                                <Media className='MediaTextHome2'>
                                    {datass.price} €
                            </Media>
                            </div>
 </button>
```

2

```
  let addedItems = this.props.items.length ?
        (
            this.props.items.map(item => {
                return (
     <Media className='MediaTextHome2'>
                                {item.quantity} €
                            </Media>
```

Comment: Try to make the explanation clear i cant understand your question from here.